# C++ Generic Data Type

Tags: c++, boost-any

Whats the best approach to a `fast` generic data type in C++. I have an event system that needs to be able to pass event information around the program.

```
sendEvent(123, "a String", aFloat, aVec3, etc); // sendEvent(EventID, EventArg, EventArg ...);

eventData.at(0).asFloat();
eventData.at(1).asInt(); // etc.
```

Until now I only needed float/int/ptr, and I handled this inside a union. but now I've got a few most structures and this is becoming a little more complex, so I'm revisiting it.

I had a dig through `boost::any` but this is too slow, there could be alot of data flying around, but this idea seems like the right direction.

I had a rather naive shot with using void* data hold but that got very ugly quickly.

Comment: If you only have a few specified types that you need to pass, and not really *any* arbitrary type, then maybe a smart pointer containing a union?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a limited set of supported types, you can try `boost::variant`. It's more or less a better union. It avoids the heap allocations that `boost::any` is using and should give maximum performance.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/variant.html

Example:

```
// create a variant capable of storing int, float and string
boost::variant<int, float, std::string> eventData;
eventData = 42.f; // store a float
float f = boost::get<float>(eventData); // get the float
```